# Mistake in variance of binomial, Jacod and Protter?

Tags: probability

In Jacod and Protter example 1 on page 119, they say that the variance of a binomially distributed random variable $Y$ with parameter $p$ and $n$ trials is given by

$$\sigma_Y^2 = \sum_{j=0}^n (j-np)^2 \binom{n}{j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}. $$
But from what I can see
$$\sigma_Y^2 = E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2 = \sum_{j=0}^n j^2 \binom{n}{j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j} - (np)^2
=\sum_{j=0}^n (j^2-(np)^2) \binom{n}{j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}. $$
Is it a mistake or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are both correct. If you multiply the first one out, you get the $j^2$ term, a $+(np)^2$ term, and $-2jnp$, but you can replace the $j$ by $np$ since the sum over these two is the same, so that makes $-(np)^2$ in total.

Their version is just the definition of the variance – the mean squared deviation from the mean.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you